# Is there a way to hide the new "used by" metric on your GitHub repos?

Tags: github

I've noticed some, but not all, repos on GitHub have a new "used by" metric:

[image]

Is there a setting to toggle this on or off? I can imagine some public repos would not want this to show up.

Answer (score 2):

No need to worry about this now. GitHub has removed "Used By" metric in the latest update.